# Tikz Pattern lines are not exactly straight

Tags: tikz-pgf

I do have a short problem with Tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern=north east lines] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I simply want to fill differently shaped areas with north east lines. Which is done as is it's supposed to be. But the problem i can not figure out is why they are not exactly straight. Certainly nobody would notice in print but in the pdf it just looks distorted. Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: This is yet another side effect of the PDF-viewer, has nothing to do with `TikZ` or `pstricks` if that is used. Try zoom in and see if it disappears? It does in my case.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52704/12774

Answer (score 4):

As is mentioned in the comment above, the display is dependent on your choice of pdf viewer. For example in Acrobat X we get the following in a 100%, 300% and 500% zoom:

[image][image][image]

Now in SumatraPDF, you get the following:

[image][image][image]

Notice how the display varies with the viewer. Hence there is no way to improve on this. The printing output will not be affected.

Comment: But who prints documents these days? ;-)

Comment: Its true, I scarcely print except for exams. But even there one expects the best from LaTeX.