# How to smoothen an Asymptote plot

Tags: eps, asymptote

I tried to plot this function and export it as `.eps` file but the plot does not look smooth at all

[image]

I'm absolute beginner at this tool, Is it a number of samples problem or what?

Comment: Hi! What program do you use to generate the plot? If it's LaTeX, could you please show the [Minimal Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that produces it, please?

Comment: My code is:

size(8cm,6cm,IgnoreAspect); 
import graph;

real f(real x){return Sin(x)^4;}
real g(real x){return (Sin(x)^2)*(Cos((x/2)^2));}

xlimits(0, 180);
labely(1,2W);
yaxis(Label("$y$",position=EndPoint, align=2E),Ticks("%",extend=true), Arrow);
xaxis(Label("$x$",position=EndPoint, align=2E), Arrow);
draw(graph(f, 0, 180));
draw(graph(g, 0, 180));
labelx(180,2S);

Comment: If you simply want the graph to look smoother, add the parameter `operator ..` as the last parameter to the `graph` command. To set the sample size of a particular graph to--say--50, add the parameter `n=50` to a particular `graph` command.

Comment: @microarm15 Please, add the code to your question, rather than in a comment.

Comment: @Charles Staats

Thank you, but how to put the number of samples exactly?

I inserted the .. and it has been enhanced a bit, but still looks pixelated, I cannot insert the number of samples

Comment: @microarm15 Like this: `draw(graph(g, 0, 180, n=500, join=operator ..)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to increase the sampling rate, which is in the variable `ngraph` and defaults to 100. Here's the result with 1000:

```
size(8cm,6cm,IgnoreAspect);
import graph;
ngraph=1000;
real f(real x){return Sin(x)^4;}
real g(real x){return (Sin(x)^2)*(Cos((x/2)^2));}
xlimits(0, 180);
labely(1,2W);
yaxis(Label("$y$",position=EndPoint, align=2E),Ticks("%",extend=true), Arrow);
xaxis(Label("$x$",position=EndPoint, align=2E), Arrow);
draw(graph(f, 0, 180));
draw(graph(g, 0, 180));
labelx(180,2S);
```

[image]

Comment: And in the interest of teaching a man to fish and all that: [here's the online documentation](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/). By specifying the function `T` you can even make the sampling not evenly spaced, if you know a priori where you need higher "resolution".

Comment: @WillieWong Let's say that the documentation is not precisely user friendly.

Comment: It still looks ragged to me here. The `pdf` output is fine, even for the OP's code, but the `eps` output is ragged.

Comment: @mafp: What viewer are you using for the `.eps` file? Is anti-aliasing enabled?

Comment: @Jake ghostview with a-a enabled. Disabling a-a improved the plot considerably. So it is mostly a viewer problem.

Answer (score 12):

This plot needs quite a large number of samples to be represented correctly. I know you're asking for a way to do this in Asymptote, but I'd like to show a way to generate the plot directly within LaTeX using the PGFPlots package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:180,
    samples=300,
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick={0,180},
    enlarge x limits=upper,
    enlarge y limits
]
\addplot [thick, red, smooth] {(sin(x)^2)};
\addplot [
    thick,
    smooth,
    line join=round % To avoid overshoots
] {(sin(x)^2)*(cos((x/2)^2))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `sin(x)^2` should be `sin(x)^4`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit: I know, but I thought that this version is prettier `=)`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the Asymptote specific things (sampling resolution), the problem is heavily influenced by the `eps` viewer. As already discussed at [My .eps images appear to lack resolution, but turn out crisp after compiling my document, what's going on?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52704/21591), line smoothing in the viewer is the culprit. I get the same rags in the `eps` plot as you with anti-aliasing on in ghostview, turning anti-aliasing off improved the output quite a bit. That being said, the `pdf` built from your and egreg's code looks much better, as it is rendered by [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org). Also, in print even the `eps` plot might look smooth.