# Tikz diagonal filling pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I would like diagonal line pattern and I also found it in the documentation, but something goes wrong:

[image]

The two pattern should consist of solid lines in two directions.

MEW:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}

\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1}]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b1) at (1,1);
\coordinate (b2) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (b3) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (b4) at (1,-1);
\fill[pattern=north west lines]
   ($(b1)$) -- ($(b2)$) -- ($(b3)$);
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
   ($(b1)$) -- ($(b2)$) -- ($(b4)$);
\draw[extended line=1mm] (b3) -- (b1);
\draw[extended line=1mm] (b4) -- (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Interesting: it must be a bug. The picture for the MEW is from www.overleaf.com; but if I compile it in my document with (miktext 2019) I get

[image: img]

The quality is poor (because the pattern are made in small square I suppose instead of clipping a nice "infinite" pattern) but at least it is what it was supposed to do.

Comment: If I compile your code, I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGFGq.png

Comment: @leandriis I just noticed it myself and edited the question...strange

Comment: @leandriis Your pic is better than my second one

Comment: Did you try different zoom factors? With a factor of 100% I also get the output you show. If I increase the factor in adobe reader, the image is closer to my screenshot.

Comment: @leandriis You are right it a question of rendering (1) paper very good (2) evince very good (3) chome pdf redaer bad

Comment: Probably related? [Tikz Pattern lines are not exactly straight](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51067/134144)

Comment: Okular is bad too. I suppose this is an effect of antialiasing for sub-pixel width lines. It's a pity indeed; these days very few documents are really printed and so we loose most of the "beautiful look" of TeX this way...

Comment: I feel there is a type. "MEW" is misspelled. It should be "MEOW". ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Seems to be a job for `patterns.meta`, which was looming in the dark until it got added recently to the pgfmanual.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzdeclarepattern{
  name=arrows,
  type=uncolored,
  bottom left={(-.1pt,-.1pt)},
  top right={(12.1pt,8.1pt)},
  tile size={(12pt,8pt)},
  tile transformation={rotate=45},
  code={
\tikzset{x=1pt,y=1pt}
\draw [-stealth] (0,2) -- (6,2); 
\draw [-stealth] (6,6) -- (12,6); 
} }
\tikzdeclarepattern{
  name=north east stripes,
  type=uncolored,
  bottom left={(-.1pt,-.1pt)},
  top right={(12.1pt,8.1pt)},
  tile size={(12pt,8pt)},
  tile transformation={rotate=45},
  code={
\tikzset{x=1pt,y=1pt}
\draw  (0,2) -- (6,2); 
\draw  (6,6) -- (12,6); 
} }
\tikzdeclarepattern{
  name=north west stripes,
  type=uncolored,
  bottom left={(-.1pt,-.1pt)},
  top right={(12.1pt,8.1pt)},
  tile size={(12pt,8pt)},
  tile transformation={rotate=-45},
  code={
\tikzset{x=1pt,y=1pt}
\draw  (1,2) -- (5,2); 
\draw  (7,6) -- (11,6); 
} }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [pattern=arrows] (-2,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw [pattern=north east stripes] (2,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,-2);
\draw [pattern=north west stripes] (-2,2) -- (0,0) -- (-2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using square tiles one can reproduce the screen shot more precisely.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzdeclarepattern{name=arrows,
  type=uncolored,
  bottom left={(-.1pt,-.1pt)},
  top right={(10.1pt,10.1pt)},
  tile size={(10pt,10pt)},
  tile transformation={rotate=45},
  code={
\tikzset{x=1pt,y=1pt}
\draw [-stealth] (0,2.5) -- (5,2.5); 
\draw [-stealth] (5,7.5) -- (10,7.5); 
} }
\tikzdeclarepattern{name=north east stripes,
  type=uncolored,
  bottom left={(-.1pt,-.1pt)},
  top right={(10.1pt,10.1pt)},
  tile size={(10pt,10pt)},
  tile transformation={rotate=45},
  code={
\tikzset{x=1pt,y=1pt}
\draw  (0,2.5) -- (5,2.5) (5,7.5) -- (10,7.5); 
} }
\tikzdeclarepattern{name=north west stripes,
  type=uncolored,
  bottom left={(-.1pt,-.1pt)},
  top right={(10.1pt,10.1pt)},
  tile size={(10pt,10pt)},
  tile transformation={rotate=-45},
  code={
\tikzset{x=1pt,y=1pt}
\draw (1,2.5) -- (5,2.5)  (6,7.5) -- (10,7.5); 
} }
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [pattern=arrows] (-3.2,3.2) -- (0,0) -- (3.2,3.2);
 \draw [pattern=north east stripes] (3.2,3.2) -- (0,0) -- (3.2,-3.2);
 \draw [pattern=north west stripes] (-3.2,3.2) -- (0,0) -- (-3.2,-3.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tested this both with `preview` and `acroread` in various magnifications and did not see any issue.